# How to append a string in between a url in PHP

Tags: php, string, url, append

I want to add a string between a url string using PHP.

```
$link = 'http://localhost/wordpress/mypage';
$string = 'nl/';
```

I want the new link to be like this:

```
$newlink = 'http://localhost/wordpress/nl/mypage';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one-of-the way to achieve it, using `substr_replace()`:

```
$someString = 'http://localhost/wordpress/mypage';
$string = 'nl/';

echo substr_replace($someString, $string, strpos($someString, 'mypage'), 0);
```

Output:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/nl/mypage
```

Another method using `str_replace()`:

```
$someString = 'http://localhost/wordpress/mypage';

echo str_replace('wordpress/', 'wordpress/nl/', $someString);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an easiest way you can do.

```
$string = 'nl/';
$link = 'http://localhost/wordpress/'.$string.'mypage';
```

You can set the `$string` dynamic or static as you wanted to.

`echo $link;`  Result : `http://localhost/wordpress/nl/mypage`